# application privileges of an installation

Tags: privileges, administrative

I have developed an application (e.g example.exe). If I double click on this executable, it starts and all is ok. Instead, If I create a setup to install this application, this application installed starts only if it has administrative privileges. How is it possible to run the application also without administrative privileges?

Comment: Well, why does it not start if you don't?

Comment: The problem was I was writing on a folder writable only with administrative privileges. once I change the folder where i was writing, the problem solved